# Setting a custom working directory for a process started with exec

Tags: c, linux, exec, working-directory

I am calling `execv` in my C code to launch an executable, but I want to set its working directory to something custom.

For example, in one case, I am launching `ls`, but it lists the files in my original program's directory. But I want to set the working directory to something custom. How will I achieve it, such that, I'll set it to `/usr/bin` and `ls` will list the files in that dir. And don't give me a specific solution for `ls`, it was just an example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`chdir(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/chdir.2.html) after a successful `fork(2)`, before execing:

```
switch (fork()) {
case 0:
    chdir(newpath); 
    execvp(...);
    break;            
}
```