# How can I execute a command in a specific folder from a C++ program?

Tags: c++, command-line

I need to execute a command in a certain folder from the command line from my C++ program. How would I do this?

My command is this: [whisper "transcribe.wav"] (without the brackets but with the quotes)

I have tried: system(cmd < whisper "transcribe.wav") but the quotes are messing things up.

I also need to run the cmd in the project folder.

Do I need to add the pathname? Where?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547528/setting-a-custom-working-directory-for-a-process-started-with-exec

Comment: A poster child example of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). You'll find that taking a step back to understand the *problem* you are actually trying to solve will produce a far better solution. That better solution will, among others, allow you to know, whether the operation succeeded, and why it failed, if it didn't. `std::system` won't do any of the aforementioned.

Answer (score 0):

If your program does not need to interact with the command, I think `std::system` is the best option. If your program needs to write to the command's input or read from its output, then using a `pipe` is a better approach. Using `fork` and `exec` are probably overkill in this context.

For your particular case, I believe the following will work:

```cpp
std::system("cd path/to/working/dir && /path/to/whisper transcribe.wav");
```

The `std::system` command will start a shell and then execute the given shell command. In this case it will change the directory and if that is successful execute `whisper`.

You may want to start by trying to execute the command string directly in the shell to make sure that works as expected. So, in the shell, run "cd /path/to/working/dir && /path/to/whisper transcribe.wav" and see if that works as expected. Once you get the shell command working, try it in the program.

Comment: The command specifically needs to include the quotes as part of the syntax. How can I make this possible?

Comment: @katerainey You can include quotation marks in the string by using [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape). In short, just prepend backslashes.